# RegionPlot from discrete data

Tags: plotting, interpolation, discrete

I have a discrete set of plots in the form (x,y,v) similar to (this is sample data, the actual data contains 13000+ plots which can be downloaded from [here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/3kdi175pylqvzzt/data.csv/file)

```
data={{0.186814, 2.75563, 0}, {0.145875, 2.35965, 0}, {-0.0190434, 
  0.635116, 0}, {-0.10058, 4.47968, 0}, {0.196213, 4.39669, 
  0}, {0.0454567, 2.7967, 0}, {-0.0103648, 2.00431, 1}}
```

I want to make a 2D plot in the {x,y} plane where v=1 and v=0.

I use the following command.

```
temp = Import["data.csv"];
data = Drop[Table[i[[{2, 3, 4}]], {i, temp}], 1];    
ListContourPlot[data, Contours -> {1}, 
     ContourStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
     ContourShading -> {Red, Green}, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

But the region boundaries are not smooth, as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Any help to improve the plot?

Comment: How about `ListPointPlot3D[data]` with `temp = Import["data.csv"];
data = Drop[Table[i[[{2, 3, 4}]], {i, temp}], 1]; `?

Comment: I want to make a 2D plot.